# How to loop through column names and conditionally subset data with each?

Tags: r

I'm looping through column names in a data frame, and I need to subset the data with those names on each iteration. I know that `DATA$column` can be replaced with `DATA[[column]]` [when looping through column names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18462789/2487476), but how can I subset with this format?

Example:

```
for (a in names(labs)) {
    for (b in names(labs)){
        if (a != b) {
        # This doesn't work but it shows what I want
          print( mean(subset(DATA, b == 1)$a) )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `mean(DATA[DATA[[b]]==1,][[a]])` ?

Comment: You can use the `select` in `subset` i.e. `mean(subset(DATA, b==a, select = a)[[1]])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexing the column of a dataframe with the name of the column can be done by `Dataframe[[columnname]]`. So you can do:

```
my.mean <- function(a, b) mean(DATA[DATA[[b]]==1,a])
outer(names(labs), names(labs), FUN = Vectorize(my.mean))
```

You get 1's in the diagonal.

Comment: My final line of code that I ended up using was `mean(DATA[DATA[[b]]==1, a][[1]])`

Answer (score 1):

As the `subset` has `select` argument, we can pass `a` using that argument.  The output of `subset` is always a `data.frame` as it has `drop=FALSE` as default argument.  But, `mean` works on `vector` or `matrix`.  Therefore, convert the `data.frame` to `vector` by extracting the first column `[[1]]`

```
for (a in names(labs)) {
   for (b in names(labs)){
    if (a != b) {     
      print( mean(subset(DATA, b == 1, select = a)[[1]]) )
   }
 }
}
```